# Webpage data scraping using Java

Tags: java, html

I am now trying to implement a simple HTML webpage scraper using Java.Now I have a small problem.
Suppose I have the following HTML fragment.

```
<div id="sr-h-left" class="sr-comp">
    <a class="link-gray-underline" id="compare_header"  rel="nofollow" href="javascript:i18nCompareProd('/serv/main/buyer/ProductCompare.jsp?nxtg=41980a1c051f-0942A6ADCF43B802');">
        <span style="cursor: pointer;" class="sr-h-o">Compare</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="sr-h-right" class="sr-summary">
    <div id="sr-num-results">
        <div class="sr-h-o-r">Showing 1 - 30 of 1,439 matches,
```

The data I am interested is the integer 1.439 shown at the bottom.I am just wondering how can I get that integer out of the HTML.
I am now considering using a regular expression,and then use the java.util.Pattern to help get the data out,but still not very clear about the process.
I would be grateful if you guys could give me some hint or idea on this data scraping.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are probably the best way to do it. Something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Showing [0-9,]+ - [0-9,]+ of ([0-9,]+) matches");
Matcher m = p.matches(scrapedHTML);
if(m.matches()) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1).replaceAll(",", ""));
    // num == 1439
}
```

I'm not sure what you meant by understanding the "process", but here's what that code does: `p` is a regular expression pattern that matches the "Showing..." line. `m` is the result of applying that pattern to the scraped HTML. If `m.matches()` is true it means the pattern matched the HTML, and `m.group(1)` will be the first regular expression group (expression in parentheses) in the pattern, which was `([0-9,]+)`, which matches a string of digits and commas, so it'll be "1,459". The `replaceAll()` call turns that into "1459", and `Integer.parseInt()` turns that into the integer 1459

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression to parse the text is one possibility.  Sometimes too, the specific text you need is in a specific div in the DOM hiearchy so you can use an xpath expression to find what you need.  Sometimes you want to look for divs of a specific class.  It depends on the specific HTML.  In addition to regular expressions, a good HTML parser will come  in handy.  I've used [Jericho HTML](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/), but there are many others out there.

Answer (score 1):

Use a HTML parser to get that piece and then use regex to get rid of the part until with "of" and the part from "matches" and on. Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with help of [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net):

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2615727;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://www.google.com/search?q=html+parser");
        HtmlElement results = page.getElementById("resultStats"); // <div id="resultStats">
        String text = results.asText(); // Results 1 - 10 of about 2,050,000 for html parser. (0.18 seconds)
        String total = text.replaceAll("^(.*about)|(for.*)$", "").trim(); // 2,050,000
        Long l = (Long) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).parse(total); // 2050000
        System.out.println(l);
    }

}
```

In your specific case you may want to replace only the URL and the following two lines in:

```
HtmlElement results = page.getElementById("sr-num-results"); // <div id="sr-num-results">
```

and

```
String total = text.replaceAll("^(.*of)|(matches.*)$", "").trim(); // 1,439
```